# How to sort documents depending on the sort of populated reference in MongoDB Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in MongoDB Mongoose and I don't know if it is possible to get shops sorted on their location. I tried this query

```
    shop.find({},{'shopName':1,'shopLocationId':1})
    .populate({path:'shopLocationId',match:{loc:{$nearSphere:{$geometry:{type:'Point',coordinates:[50,55]}}}},select:'loc -_id'})
.exec(function (err,shops) {
        if (err)
            throw err
        console.log(shops.toString())

        })
    })
```

but I get the wrong result only shops without sort.

```
var ShopSchema = new Schema({
    shopName: {type: String},
    shopLocationId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'location'}
})
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
    loc:{type: Schema.Types,`enter code here`
        coordinates :[ Number]},
    locationName:{ type: String
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add sort as an option:
`.populate(..., options: { sort: { 'fieldToSort': 'descending' } })`

Comment: infact the  $nearspher sorts the documents throught coordinates that why i don't need to add  sort: { 'fieldToSort': 'descending' }  thank you so much

Comment: @NazimKissi then perhaps you would want to use `.sort()` after you populate the location. This would sort the shops based on your field of choice

Comment: may be @Ryan Endacot you have the answer